# Why is Chrome referencing "data:text/css," in all websites?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, adblock

Whilst debugging a website I found this tag below the body of the page I was debugging:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:text/css,">
```

and I thought that some crazy Javascript-Error was adding this to my site. But I could not find anything like that in all of the project's source-code.

After checking back with Firefox I noticed, that only Chrome displays this tag in the Elements-, Resources- and Network-View. It is not visible in the "View Source" of Chrome though.

What is this about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experienced the same strange css link, and found that it is due to the AdBlockPlus (ADB) extension for Chrome that I have enabled. When I disable that extension, the link no longer occurs.

Comment: Rather than disabling the extension entirely, you can add your domain to the ADB whitelist.

Comment: I had it occur due to the Stylish extension in Firefox.